# How can I make this multi-select Bash script default to all items selected?

Tags: bash

I modified a great script I found online by Nathan Davieau on serverfault.com, but I have hit the limit to my knowledge of Bash!

It works great, apart from I have to select each item, I want it to **start with all items selected** and have to deselect them.

```
#!/bin/bash
ERROR=" "
declare -a install
declare -a options=('php' 'phpmyadmin' 'php-mysqlnd' 'php-opcache' 'mariadb-server' 'sendmail')

#===  FUNCTION  ========================================================================
#         NAME:  ACTIONS
#  DESCRIPTION:  Actions to take based on selection
# PARAMETER  1:
#=======================================================================================
function ACTIONS() {

    for ((i = 0; i < ${#options[*]}; i++)); do
        if [[ "${choices[i]}" == "+" ]]; then
            install+=(${options[i]})
        fi
    done
    echo "${install[@]}"
}

#===  FUNCTION  ========================================================================
#         NAME:  MENU
#  DESCRIPTION:  Ask for user input to toggle the name of the plugins to be installed
# PARAMETER  1:
#=======================================================================================
function MENU() {
    echo "Which packages would you like to be installed?"
    echo
    for NUM in "${!options[@]}"; do
        echo "[""${choices[NUM]:- }""]" $((NUM + 1))") ${options[NUM]}"
    done
    echo "$ERROR"
}

#Clear screen for menu
clear

#Menu loop
while MENU && read -e -p "Select the desired options using their number (again to uncheck, ENTER when done): " -n2 SELECTION && [[ -n "$SELECTION" ]]; do
    clear
    if [[ "$SELECTION" == *[[:digit:]]* && $SELECTION -ge 1 && $SELECTION -le ${#options[@]} ]]; then
        ((SELECTION--))
        if [[ "${choices[SELECTION]}" == "+" ]]; then
            choices[SELECTION]=""
        else
            choices[SELECTION]="+"
        fi
        ERROR=" "
    else
        ERROR="Invalid option: $SELECTION"
    fi
done

ACTIONS
```

Comment: BTW, under normal circumstances this wouldn't be considered a good question here -- generally, we want things that are isolated to a very specific problem, with everything unrelated to that problem removed. See the docs on building a [mcve], and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I agree in principle, but given that this was a type of script that I haven't worked with much, it seemed like a better use of my time than the countless `dos2unix` etc Qs ;-) . @Sumomo , be sure to read and absorb the principles in the provided link ;-) . Good luck to all!

Comment: Cheers! I have read and understood for the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you only need to initialize the `choices[]` (array) before you actually process them. (re-)Revised code below (with thanks to Charles Duffy) :

```
#!/bin/bash
ERROR=" "
declare -a install
declare -a options=('php' 'phpmyadmin' 'php-mysqlnd' 'php-opcache' 'mariadb-server' 'sendmail')

############### HERE's THE NEW BIT #################
declare -a choices=( "${options[@]//*/+}" )
####################################################

#===  FUNCTION  ========================================================================
#         NAME:  ACTIONS
#  DESCRIPTION:  Actions to take based on selection
# PARAMETER  1:
#=======================================================================================
function ACTIONS() {

    for ((i = 0; i < ${#options[*]}; i++)); do
        if [[ "${choices[i]}" == "+" ]]; then
            install+=(${options[i]})
        fi
    done
    echo "${install[@]}"
}

#===  FUNCTION  ========================================================================
#         NAME:  MENU
#  DESCRIPTION:  Ask for user input to toggle the name of the plugins to be installed
# PARAMETER  1:
#=======================================================================================
function MENU() {
    echo "Which packages would you like to be installed?"
    echo
    for NUM in "${!options[@]}"; do
        echo "[""${choices[NUM]:- }""]" $((NUM + 1))") ${options[NUM]}"
    done
    echo "$ERROR"
}

#Clear screen for menu
clear

#Menu loop
while MENU && read -e -p "Select the desired options using their number (again to uncheck, ENTER when done): " -n2 SELECTION && [[ -n "$SELECTION" ]]; do
    clear
    if [[ "$SELECTION" == *[[:digit:]]* && $SELECTION -ge 1 && $SELECTION -le ${#options[@]} ]]; then
        ((SELECTION--))
        if [[ "${choices[SELECTION]}" == "+" ]]; then
            choices[SELECTION]=""
        else
            choices[SELECTION]="+"
        fi
        ERROR=" "
    else
        ERROR="Invalid option: $SELECTION"
    fi
done

ACTIONS
```

Sorry, but I can't afford the time to give a blow by blow description of how all this works. In this case, the traditional shell debugging tool of `set -vx` (paired with `set +vx`) might be a challenge to interpret for a newbie. Experiment only when  you can spare the time.

Note that the key bit of code is where the `+` gets toggled :

```
if [[ "${choices[SELECTION]}" == "+" ]]; then
    choices[SELECTION]=""
else
    choices[SELECTION]="+"
fi
```

IHTH

Comment: Couldn't this answer be a one-liner? `choices=( "${options[@]//*/+}" )`, immediately after the `options` assignment at the top.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Oh yeah, very good! If you don't mind I'll borrow that great idea ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: Absolutely feel free to. :)